# TypeError sqlite python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, typeerror

I am new to sqlite in python and I am trying to do the following:

Extract a certain value from a row in a table and compare it to 100 (it's an INT type normally).
**school** is a table where I have the following attributes: **id, class, nbstudent, nbteachers, nbrepresentative**

I use the following function:

```
def select_school_value(conn, class,m):
    """
    Query school by class

    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM school WHERE class=?", (class,))
    record = cur.fetchone()

    return record[m]
```

*The function's parameter m is just a number that depends on which attribute I want to extract for the comparaison: nbstudent is m=2, nbteacher is m=3..*

When I use my function select_school_value() and compare the returned value with 100, I have a TypeError, the return is a NoneType.
How can I have a integer type return **(the type of the attribute I need)**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide, in text form, some test data. It seems your table contains a NULL, which is translated to None in Python.

Comment: Ilja Everilä exactly what happened yes, I just figured out that!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is in `class` parameter that you pass to your function and query. Rename it somehow, because Python treats it like a pointer to some class within python code.
Also you have that `class=?` part which means actuallly "find a class which equals '?'". It should be rewritten too.

I suggest trying this:

```
def select_school_value(conn,cl,m):
    """
    Query school by class

    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM school WHERE class={}".format(cl))
    record = cur.fetchone()

    return record[m]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I used your code I had a sqlite3.OperationalError
Otherwise my code is working now (I didn't change anything, mysteries of the code I suppose).

Comment: Please don't use string formatting for passing values to queries. It is prone to errors and SQL injection. The original code attempt was right in that it used the DB driver placeholders and passed arguments to `execute()` separately.